# Error Plugin with name Port not found. Step name: Port while usng aws ssm start-session

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, aws-ssm

I am trying to run an Ansible playbook to target host.
I created one dynamic ec2 inventory. As you can see in below code it's using the proxy command `aws ssm start-session`. While executing tasks I am getting the following error

> Plugin with name Port not found. Step name: Port\n\r\ndebug1: ssh_exchange_identification: \n\r\nssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host\r\n"

```yaml
- name: create hosts inventory
  add_host:
    name: "{{item.tags.Name}}"
    groups: target_vm_group
    ansible_ssh_common_args: -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ProxyCommand="sh -c \"aws ssm start-session --target %h --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession --profile xyz --debug --region us-east-1 --cli-read-timeout 0 --cli-connect-timeout 0 --parameters 'portNumber=%p'\""
    ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ssh_user}}"
    ansible_become_pass: "{{ssh_password}}"
    ansible_ssh_host: "{{item.instance_id}}"
    ansible_user: "{{ssh_user}}"
    env_ec2_name: "{{item.tags.Name}}"
    ip_address: "{{item.private_ip_address}}"
    instance_id: "{{item.instance_id}}"
    env_name: "{{item.tags.EnvironmentName}}"
  with_items: "{{ ec2s.instances }}"
```

Comment: is %h resolving correctly to the instanceId you want to connect to?

Comment: yes, i can see  following ansible logs
Arguments entered to CLI: [\'ssm\', \'start-session\', \'--target\', \'i-0c1fb7effa668XXXX\', \'--document-name\', \'AWS-StartSSHSession\', \'--profile\', \'xyz\', \'--debug\', \'--region\', \'us-east-1\', \'--cli-read-timeout\', \'0\', \'--cli-connect-timeout\', \'0\', \'--parameters\', \'portNumber=22\']

Comment: Please run `ansible-playbook` command with additional parameter `-vvv` and add more debug output to you post.